# Why do I get a node_modules error when I try to initialize a new Stencil project?

Tags: node.js, bigcommerce

I'm just beginning to use Bigcommerce's Stencil language and I'm stuck in the documentation when I attempt to initialize their sample project (`https://github.com/bigcommerce-stencil/stencil.git`).

I've cloned the repo and done the necessary installations (I've tried this using Node version 4.2.1, 4.2.3, and 5.0.0). When I type `stencil init` from within the stencil directory, this is the error message I get:

```
Potentially unhandled rejection [6] Error: Error loading "node_modules/core-js/library/fn/get-iterator" at file:/Users/Eric/Development/econify/stencil/assets/node_modules/core-js/library/fn/get-iterator.js
Error loading "node_modules/core-js/library/fn/get-iterator" from "js/app" at file:/Users/Eric/Development/econify/stencil/assets/js/app.js
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Eric/Development/econify/stencil/assets/node_modules/core-js/library/fn/get-iterator.js' at Error (native)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you run JSPM install?

Comment: Thanks for your response! Yeah, I get the same error message after running jspm install.

Comment: Do you see that it successfully installs the required dependencies?

Comment: It appears to. I see a number of green oks and one warning:
`warn Using local override for github:hubspot/pace@1.0.2`